# Making objects linked

Tags: modeling, linked-data

I used to do many copies of an object using Shift+D (didn't know about Alt+D then). Can I make these objects linked now and keep their positions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To link objects after you created them, simply select all the objects, with the original object as the active one. and press Ctrl + L, then choose what properties you want to link.